# Is this still a closure?

Tags: c#, .net, function, closures, anonymous-methods

The testit() method is a closure. aString has fallen out of scope but testit() can still execute on it.  testit2() is using a variable that hasn't fallen out of scope (mystring) but which was also not been passed into testit2().  Is testit2() considered a closure?

```
string mystring = "hello world";
Action testit = new Action(delegate { string aString = "in anon method"; Debug.WriteLine(aString); });
testit();

//capture mystring.  Is this still a closure?
Action testit2 = new Action(delegate { Debug.WriteLine(mystring); });
//mystring is still in scope
testit2();
```

In the second example, mystring can be updated outside of the method and those changes will be reflected in testit2().  This doesn't behave like a normal method, which would only be able to capture mystring as a parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both examples are anonymous functions.  The second of which use a closure in order to capture the local variables.  The scope lifetime of the variable with respect to the anonymous function does not affect whether or not a closure is created to use it.  As long as the variable is defined outside a anonymous function and used within, a closure will be created.

The first anonymous function uses no local state, therefore does not need a closure.  It should compile down to a static method.

This is necessary because the anonymous function can live past the lifetime of the current function.  Therefore all locals used in a anonymous function must be captured in order to execute the delegate at a later time.

Comment: They're anonymous methods, not lambda expressions (in C# terminology anyway). Both lambda expressions and anonymous methods count as anonymous functions, however.

Comment: I feel bad nit-picking terminology with a Softie :)

Comment: @Jon, nitpicks are welcome.  Another chance to learn something new.  I didn't know anonymous function was the universal term for these two different scenarios.  I've taken to just calling them lambda's everywhere.  Anonymous function is more difficult to type though ;)

Answer (score 3):

A closure does not capture the *values* in scope, but the actual *definition* of the scope. So any other piece of code that has a reference to the same scope can modify variables within it.

Comment: This kind of closure is known as a "lexical closure" - it captures the lexical scope.

Answer (score 1):

`testit` isn't as much of a closure as `testit2` is really - it's only using a *locally defined* variable, rather than one in the "parent" environment (such as `mystring`).

However, I'd argue that both are closures as they have the *ability* to capture variables from their enclosing environment, due to anonymous methods.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking at your example from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/closures-in-net.  counter is defined just as testit() defines aString.  I believe it means the example you gave isn't the strongest case for closures, which seems to be what you've stated for testit().

Comment: @4thspace: No, read the example again. counter is defined outside the anonymous method, more like mystring.