# What are 'closures' in C#?

Tags: c#, closures

#### Duplicate

> [Closures in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/closures-in-net)

What are closures in C#?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/closures-in-net

Comment: Duplicate maybe; the accepted answer though is particularly succinct.

Comment: Any practical examples available for usage of closures?

Comment: After I read "*A closure is a function that captures the bindings of free variables in its lexical context*" and only understood the word '*function*' in the sentence,  I was very happy to find [Justin Etheredge article](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/) whom author deserves a prize for explaining this using a simple and funny wording.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

A [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) in C# takes the form of an in-line delegate/[anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx). A [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) is attached to its parent method meaning that variables defined in parent's method body can be referenced from within the anonymous method.

**Example:**

```
public Person FindById(int id)
{
    return this.Find(delegate(Person p)
    {
        return (p.Id == id);
    });
}
```

You could also take a look at [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/Closure.html) or [Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) blogs. I am sure you will be able to get a more "In Depth" breakdown from at least one of them....

**Example for C# 6:**

```
public Person FindById(int id)
{
    return this.Find(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
public Person FindById(int id) => this.Find(p => p.Id == id);
```

Comment: anyone have a c# 6 or 7 update for this answer?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' There you go!

Comment: @NickBull thanks so much. now that it is 2 years later, i am actually looking for the latest and greatest version, around 8.3?

Comment: No differences I can think of - C#7/8 didn't offer much in the way of affecting anonymous methods/closure syntax