# Wrong value of i while multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am trying to use multithreading to call this function. When I run the program I get an exception "Index out of range". When I try to print the values of 'i' I get serviceids list.count each times.

In my case the loop should go from 0 to 1 and print
The value of i this time is 0
The value of i this time is 1

but it prints both times

The value of i this time is 2
The value of i this time is 2

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it ?
        DataDownloader downloader = new DataDownloader();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < serviceidslist.Count; i++)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs argss)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

            Console.WriteLine("The value of i this time is {0}", i);
            downloader.DoDownload(serviceidslist[i]);



        });

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: To me, it looks _very_ strange to construct `BackgroundWorker` instances inside a loop.

Comment: I want to create number of threads equal to serviceidlist.count

Comment: There are times when a `BackgroundWorker` is the right tool for a job - at other times it is not. This is such a case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an idea, but add a local variable and assign it to `i`:

`int temp = i;`

Then use it:

```
Console.WriteLine("The value of i this time is {0}", temp);
downloader.DoDownload(serviceidslist[temp]);
```

I think the issue could be that your BackgroundWorker is closing over the variable and not the value hence the need to store a copy of it each time in your loop.

also see here

[What are 'closures' in C#? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c)

Comment: No worries, mark as the answer when possible, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the usage of the variable **i**.

Try with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < serviceidslist.Count; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs argss)
    {
        BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

        Console.WriteLine("The value of i this time is {0}", index );
        downloader.DoDownload(serviceidslist[index ]);



    });

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}`
```