# C# Unity Wrong argument of the function in onClick event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I'm adding methods to `onClick` buttons the argument of the function is always `const = array of buttons.length + 1`.  Where did I go wrong?

`all_buttons` not empty. I clicked on three different buttons.
Unity log screenshot: [link](https://s12.postimg.org/ijk2y26rh/T6uh_Xda_Uv_JI.jpg)

```
Button[] all_buttons = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
for (int i = 0; i < all_buttons.Length; i++) {
    Debug.LogWarning(all_buttons[i]+" => addLoad with index "+ (m_LvlStartIndex + i));
    if (levelScript)
        all_buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Load(m_LvlStartIndex+i));
}

public void Load(int level) {
    Debug.LogWarning("Loading "+level+" level...");
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
}
```

Update:
change this

```
all_buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Load(m_LvlStartIndex+i));
```

to

```
int tempI = i;
all_buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Load(m_LvlStartIndex+tempI));
```

Thanks to all!!

Comment: You pass `m_LvlStartIndex + i` as a parameter in all the event handlers. By the time those handlers actually get called, `i` is equal to `all_buttons.Length`. So if `m_LvlStartIndex` is equal to 1, the parameter will be exactly what you're getting.

Comment: @Abion47 how come t works at all? i would expect it to throw an error because 'i' is gone after the for loop is finished right?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156493/c-sharp-anonymous-function-scope-in-unity3d/40157738#40157738

Comment: @turnipinindia It's because of closure. In a nutshell, because the event handlers are declared in the loop scope they are considered part of the scope, so `i` won't get disposed as long as the event handlers exist.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Indeed, it was necessary to "temp" a variable "i" and after this use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line of code:

```
all_buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Load(m_LvlStartIndex+i));
```

You are supposed to save i to a temporary variable before using it with the `AddListener` function. The code below should fix it:

```
int tempI = i;
all_buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Load(m_LvlStartIndex+tempI));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem of closure (See [What are 'closures' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c)). Try this instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < all_buttons.Length; i++) {
    int index = i ;
    if (levelScript)
        all_buttons[index].onClick.AddListener(() => Load(m_LvlStartIndex+index));
}
```

Comment: Basically what you did is just copy my answer, rename the `tempI` variable to `index` then put it as an answer.

Comment: Check the dates my friend ;)

Comment: I clicked on the oldest bar and my answer is the oldest. We will verify this in a couple of days when it starts to show the actual date and time. I will apologize if I am wrong.