# Can't pass func arguments within method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a `Func<TResponse, T1, T2>` through to this method. I keep getting a syntax error for "method()" though. It says it needs two arguments which makes sense, but how do I pass it to the method? I've assigned them as T1 and T2.

How can I make this return the TResponse as well?

The way I'm calling it (the func I want to use to call the method).

```
_service.Count(fileDate (DateTime), cycle int));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public TResponse ExecuteAndLog<T1, T2,TResponse>(Guid id, string Name, Func<T1, T2, TResponse> method) where TResponse : class
{
    try
    {
        Log(id, Name);
        TResponse x = method();
        Log(id, Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(id, Name);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo because you're just trying to call a method without the required number of parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you actually want this....

```
public TResponse ExecuteAndLog<TResponse>(Guid id, string Name, Func<TResponse> method) where TResponse : class
{
    try
    {
        Log(id, Name);
        TResponse x = method();
        Log(id, Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(id, Name);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And you'd call it with

```
var response = ExecuteAndLog(someGuid, someName, () => _service.Count(fileDate, cycle));
```

This way you only need one prototype of ExecuteAndLog. If you include the inputs in the `Func` (as you did in your example), you'd have to pass the arguments through, and you'd need a different version of ExecuteAndLog for each possible service call signature.

Note: Whenever you use a lambda expression this way, be careful of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c).

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this way from the beginning... I would just add a `return x;` so this compiles, though

Answer (score 2):

If `method` should receive two parameters, you need to pass them:

```
public TResponse ExecuteAndLog<T1, T2,TResponse>(Guid id, string Name, Func<T1, T2, TResponse> method, T1 arg1, T2 arg2) where TResponse : class
{
    try
    {
        Log(id, Name);
        TResponse x = method(arg1, arg2);
        Log(id, Name);

        return x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(id, Name);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes heaps of sense! I was getting the format for the method signature wrong and got confused. Thank you.

Comment: How would I call this function now using _service.Count(fileDate (DateTime), cycle int))?

Comment: @magna_nz You would call it using `ExecuteAndLog(someGuid, someString, _service.Count, fileDate, cycle)`