# Writing a generic in C# to return data type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Need some guidance on writing a C# generic to return the data type from a SQL database. I'm doing a read from my data base to get the data type from 'SetKey'. I can return them as strings but I wish to cast them into an int, in this particular example below.  This what I have so far. Running into a couple of errors below where I have commented. I'm fairly new at this so any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you declare a variable within a code block (i.e. between `{` and `}`), the variable is private with respect to that code block. So `dataTypeModel` cannot be returned because it is declared within a code block above. You probably need to declare `dataTypeModel` outside of the delegate, turning it into a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c).

Comment: I'm always curious why people bother rolling their own ORMs when there are a proliferation of good ones already. No one rolls their own IIS, file readers, email senders etc; what makes people want to reinvent the data access wheel incessantly?

Comment: Despiste the error of the variable scope pointed out by @johnWu you would need to make the delegate logic generic also (do not use int but T)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `dataTypeModel` is not declared in any point of your code.

If you want to return in a Generic way you should do something like :

```
public DataTypeModel<T> GetDataType<T>(string str) where T : class
    {
        List<DataTypeDomain> dataTypeDomain = new List<DataTypeDomain>();
        _dataProvider.ExecuteCmd(
            "config_select_by_key",
            inputParamMapper: delegate (SqlParameterCollection paramCol)
            {
                paramCol.AddWithValue("@ConfigKey", str);
            },
            singleRecordMapper: delegate (IDataReader reader, short set)
            {
                int i = 0;
                DataTypeModel<int> dataTypeModel = new DataTypeModel<int>();
                string key = string.Format("Key{0}", i);
                DataTypeDomain dtd = dataTypeDomain.Find(x => x.ConfigKey == key);
                dataTypeModel.ConfigKey = dtd.ConfigKey;
                dataTypeModel.ConfigValue = int.Parse(dtd.ConfigValue);
            }
        );
        return new DataTypeModel<T>()
        {
            ConfigKey = "What your key is",
            ConfigValue = dataTypeDomain.First() as T //Supposing that the list only contains one config element , if not, you should change your method return type to a List<DataTypeModel<T>> and return a List doing this for each element.
        };
    }
```

Then in your interface :

```
public interface IDataTypeService
{
    DataTypeModel<T> GetDataType<T>(string str) where T : class;
}
```

***Quick Explanation***

When you are using generics you should specify the T on the methods like :

```
DataTypeModel<T> GetDataType<T>(string str) --> Only use T inside method scope
```

The other way to declare `T` is at class/interface level like :

```
public interface IDataTypeService<T>  --> With this you can use `T` in all of the class/interface
```

Also,if you want to specify some constraints that `T` should follow you can do it with :

```
where T : class;  --> In our case this allow us to cast the object to T
```

The code is not tested but I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep the `T` open in your interface definition. You have to close the type like

```
DataTypeModel<SomeType> GetDataType(string str);
```