# Is there a way to supply any number of types in a generic method?

Tags: c#

What I mean is I have a method like this:

```
public static void CrossThreadUpdate<T1, T2, T3>(this Form form, Action<T1, T2, T3> action, object[] parms)
{
    form.BeginInvoke(action, parms);
}
```

but I don't want to have to create the same function for `<T1>, <T1, T2>, <T1, T2, T3>, <T1, T2, T3, T4>, etc.` I'm imagining something similar to `Foo(params string[] bar)`.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  The number of parameters must be known at compile-time.

Comment: This feature is called "variadic generics" and it is quite rare. I believe TypeScript has done some work in this area, but C# certainly has not.

Answer (score 5):

I would just do it this way:

```
public static void CrossThreadUpdate(this Form form, Action action) 
{
    form.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

And call it this way, using [closed variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c) instead of trying to pass the parameters separately:

```
this.CrossThreadUpdate( () => someAction(param1, param2, param3) );
```

This has the additional advantage of being type-safe, whereas `params object[]` is not, and would also result in boxing for struct types.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but it's actually a lot nicer.

Comment: I actually use this pattern all the time with great success, and even provided it in another [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726278/2791540)