# What is the difference for fields vs properties which construct (immutable) value types in C#?

Tags: c#, value-type

Example:

```
public readonly struct Vector3
{
    public readonly float x;
    public readonly float y;
    public readonly float z;

    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public static readonly Vector3 oneField = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    public static Vector3 oneProperty => new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);

    public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) => 
           new Vector3(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y, lhs.z + rhs.z);
}
```

How exactly does the behaviour differ when doing:

`var v = Vector3.oneField + Vector3.oneField`

vs

`var v = Vector3.oneProperty + Vector3.oneProperty`

From my understanding the content of the field is loaded and stored in the Heap/RAM when the (relevant part of the) program is loaded, the value is then copied from there into the stack twice when the + operator is called.

While the property will allocate the memory directly on the stack twice when the + operator is called.

Is that correct? And which one would be 'technically' faster? (just curious about the details)

**EDIT**

I think technically its not a property but just an "expression-bodied member", however thats irrelevant for the question, but I will correct it for clarity if necessary.

Comment: @GuruStron Then where is the content of a field for a struct stored when loaded into RAM? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how structs/classes get compiled, saved and loaded for execution?

Comment: `public static Vector3 oneProperty => new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);` is a property, but it will return a new instance each time it is called. `public static Vector3 oneProperty { get; } = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);` will only initialize one. Not that it matters a lot in this case.

Comment: On stack, not heap. Unless boxed/being part of reference type structs (value type) are placed on stack.

Comment: `oneField` is instantiating a new `Vector3` only one time and use it every time, while `oneProperty` is instantiating a new one everytime it is called.

Comment: @GuruStron It was explained to me that the Stack is specifically for short-lived objects, that are used in the current program execution and is a temporary space for objects to be processed. However a field lives as long as the program is loaded. It would therefor occupy stack space until the program finishes execution?

Comment: @TheHelpfulHelper yes, you are correct, my bad, `oneField` is static field one so it will be placed in heap (but should be in [gen 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#generations)) and value will be copied to stack.

Comment: @TheHelpfulHelper as for being faster, you should check yourself but I would say the first one should be faster but in most cases difference should be negligible.

Comment: @GuruStron Ahh right I was implicitly thinking about a static field, not an instance field. Thanks for the clarification. Also Im specifically interested in the implementation details of the CLR / JIT Compiler, because it helps me understand how these things work.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoKwgZgAJYBDAEwgDtcBPegZwygBXMBnoA1GCOi0qAbyr1F9OoxisO3egDNcEJqIQBuBUpXM2nHjr2iuxykuUNzGq7v30AXvZOKVEqShaAAprDwQ0bXdbSLDRTwBKX3p5B0clDAALbF4AOgR6AF56I2THLJzcnmK7MozsvM8ir3tHAF8qZJVCUiRVdUtxSQxpeg4YADFsGFwWZvYYAHchwJDSLUj1za0E1tMGHr6AkaCxhYAFKAgABxgoDGqAPnoF5ePpYK36L/XdzrS/AdeisTgwbnd9NB6ABqYLvU64TK8SLw5xIhJFZ51dKvEEfRF5ArQxhI/KRAlVGEkvJccmkprEqD0v6UDrUSjdYj0ABCEGA9DkXWIxGSqXSSgAbkwoPQJc1UblxlMZnNiQqldNZntxVKZRKucV1Rcrrd7jw1cNpIrjeCzdr6Gy2VQgA=

Comment: The fundamental mechanical difference between your field and property is that the property is declared with a _method_ body, which is executed each time it's called. Note that you could have used `Vector3 oneProperty { get; } = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);` instead, which is still a property and retains property semantics, but _mechanically_ would be identical to the field (simple property getters like that are inlined at JIT compile time), See duplicates for elaboration on this explanation and other details distinguishing fields and properties.

Answer (score -1):

Fields are *read*; properties are *executed*.

This code...

```
var v = Vector3.oneField + Vector3.oneField
```

...reads two fields and adds them. Nothing is created or allocated (except a location to store the result, `v`, which *could* be on the stack but could also be somewhere else, e.g. if the variable is [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c).).

This code...

```
var v = Vector3.oneProperty + Vector3.oneProperty
```

...executes two properties and adds their results. Thus the `oneProperty` getter is executed twice.

Because the property getter contains the `new` keyword, it is going to execute `new` each time it is called, which creates a new instance. So in this example, three instances of `Vector3` are created-- two that are added and one that is the result of the addition.