# How do I pass an argument to an event handler when the event handler is a delegate and doesn't include that argument?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method as follows:

```
public static void RegisterForMessage(System.Windows.Window window, Action action)
        {
            HwndSource hWndSource;
            WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
            hWndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(wih.Handle);
            hWndSource.AddHook(hwndSourceHook);
        }
```

i want to take action from user and pass into hwndSourceHook method:

```
private static IntPtr hwndSourceHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            // Action must be run here
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

but i dont know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hwndSourceHook` has a [specific signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsourcehook) that you can't change, which means you can't add a parameter to its signature. You can only pass an event handler to `hWndSource.AddHook` that matches the signature

```cs
public delegate IntPtr HwndSourceHook(
    IntPtr hwnd, 
    int msg, 
    IntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam, 
    ref bool handled);
```

One option is to use an anonymous function instead of declaring a separate method for your handler, like this:

```cs
public static void RegisterForMessage(System.Windows.Window window, Action action)
{
    HwndSource hWndSource;
    WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
    hWndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(wih.Handle);
    HwndSourceHook eventHandler = (IntPtr hwnd, 
                                   int msg, 
                                   IntPtr param, 
                                   IntPtr lParam, 
                                   ref bool handled) =>
    {
        action.Invoke();
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    };
    hWndSource.AddHook(eventHandler);
}
```

Instead of putting the event handler in a separately declared method we're
declaring it inline within `RegisterToMethod`. That allows us to include the
parameter passed to the outer method.

This is called a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/595488/5101046).