# Can someone explain it to me what closure is in real simple language ?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are ‘closures’ in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)

I am currently looking at lambda expression and the word closure keeps coming. Can someone explain it to me in real simple language.

Comment: If you've got a smart 5 year old, then "A closure is a first-class function with free variables that are bound in the lexical environment."

Comment: Uhm, you don't? Let your kid play with other kids instead... (note: Silly title gives silly answers...)

Comment: If you have the mental capacity of a 5-year old, chances are high that you will not understand closures.

Comment: If you have the mental capacity of a 5-year old, chances are high that you won't understand any of these answers too.

Comment: A similar question, which however motivates the "6 year old" part; notice the completely different result!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: If you've got a really smart 5 year old, then "you'll never get laid if you keep asking those questions". Problem solved.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd say this is a duplicate of: [What are ‘closures’ in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)

"In essence, a closure is a block of code which can be executed at a later time, but which maintains the environment in which it was first created - i.e. it can still use the local variables etc of the method which created it, even after that method has finished executing."

Comment: This should really be a comment. Good way to milk reputation. :P

Comment: So what would have been the appropriate thing to do for
r jorge?

Comment: What 5 year old is going to understand any of this?

Answer (score 12):

> Your shoes are in the hall; your
>   jacket is in the kitchen.  Put them
>   on, and your gloves (they're in the
>   drawer), when going outside.
>
> Now you can go playing with your cars.
>   At eleven o'clock you must go buy some
>   bread in the corner store.

Kid plays.  Forgets all the world.

Alarm clock goes off; kid sees: eleven o'clock!  Oh - go outside to buy bread using the "going outside" closure.

Comment: Most children learn to tell the time a bit later than 5. They're just busy learning numerals 1-10 aged 5. Just sayin'. ;-)

Comment: They'll listen to the buzzer.  But this is about _programming_ children, they do basic math at 5 (though they can't put on their shoes by themselves...)

Comment: mine actually keep cleaning their closure cache... :(

Comment: so the kid gets to the store at 11pm and finds the store has suffered a closure and is no longer open? i thought that's where we were going here...

Answer (score 11):

I like the [Google example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#closure_simple) for Javascript (you can morph it for C# easily). It's not something a 5 year old would understand but then I doubt *an average* 5 year old would understand what a function was.

```
/*
* When a function is defined in another function and it
*    has access to the outer function's context even after
*    the outer function returns
* An important concept to learn in Javascript
*/

function outerFunction(someNum) {
  var someString = 'Hai!';
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  function innerFunction() {
    content.innerHTML = someNum + ': ' + someString;
    content = null; // IE memory leak for DOM reference
  }
  innerFunction();
}
```

Comment: innerFunction however is not available after outerFunction returns; what's shown there is possible without closures, it can be done even in Pascal and Java!

Answer (score 8):

The below answer was to the original wording which was akin to "How to explain closures to a 5-year old."

> Take this box of legos; build yourself
>   a nice little space craft. When you go
>   to billy's house and bring your space
>   craft there; with closures you can
>   still can use all the pieces in your
>   box of legos, even though the box was left
>   in your bedroom.

Comment: Thanks! :) But cannot understand how can I `use all the pieces in your box of legos, even though the box was left in your bedroom.` This box is not in the Billy's house and I cannot go to my home from Billy's house immediately.

Comment: How a closure is implemented by a language is outside the scope of the question. How is not as important, as what you can do with a closure.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to keep it simple, then *a closure is a function with its context*. The function in the closure can still access the same variables it could when it was defined, no matter where you call it from. (In Lua, these are called *upvalues*, which I think is a very descriptive term.)

I met the concept first in Lua, and this definition helped me understand the concept. Maybe have a look at Lua: its simpleness and power is fascinating, and certainly helps to develop a certain view at other languages. Its concept of closures would be a good example to that.

Answer (score 4):

If the 5 year old knew C#, I would explain with this code sample:

```
int i = 0;
string result = null;
Action iExaminer = () =>
{
  result = i % 2 == 1 ? "Odd" : "Even";
};
i = 1;
iExaminer();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If the 5 year old was learning linq, I would explain with this code sample:

```
string name = null;
IEnumerable<Customer> query = Customers.Where(c => c.Name == name);
name = "Bob";
 // query is resolved when enumerated (which is now)
 // Where will now call our anonymous method.
foreach(var customer in query)
{
  Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);
}
```

Comment: +1 - Linq is now a core foundation-stage requirement in UK schools.

Comment: @DominicRodger Really? Can you provide some evidence of this?

Comment: @lifebalance - it's been five years, but I *think* I was joking.

Answer (score 2):

[Closure (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))  says:

In computer science, a closure is a first-class function with free variables that are bound in the lexical environment.

**Translation:**
    Closures close/attach the variables around the function, so that that function can be teleported to somewhere else and still use those variables
    e.g. suppose you are teleported to a remote location but have still access to your coffed mug lying on your table

**Example:**

```
function makefunc(x)
{
    return function(){return x}
}
```

Now using makefunc, you can make many anonymous functions which will return what you pass to makefunc

So if you want a function which returns 10, use makefunc(10)(), though pretty useless way toget back 10 :)

Comment: If makefunc read *x=42*, would it bring back into existance the then-current environment?

Comment: @René Nyffenegger, i do not understand, but with different values of x different anonymous funcs will be returned bound to different x

Answer (score 0):

When you know how to do something in general, you can specify some (or all) details and get a *closure*.

For example, you know how to buy ice-cream. Yyou know what to do if you will be in front of *any* shop.  But if you want to go to a particular shop (for example, due to a Sunday discount), you move out of house with the aim of buying ice-cream *there*.  "Buy some ice-cream at a store on the corner" is a closure of "buy some ice-cream".  In fact, all these are closures of "buy some ice-cream somewhere":

- Buy some ice-cream at the corner
- Buy two ice-creams
- Buy two ice-creams at the corner

Now go play with your friends, son! (and I bear in mind not say anything like that in front of the children)

Comment: Or, did I mix it with projection?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach to the idea in C#: [Closure](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/c/831-closure.html)