# How does a C# Memoization method retain the cache after returning a function

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

Been messing around with functional programming concepts and came across memoization.

Here's an example:

```cs
public static Func<T, TResult> Memoize<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> f) {
    var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, TResult>();
    return a => cache.GetOrAdd(a, f);
}
```

How does the returned function still have access to the dictionary object?

Comment: A reference to the dictionary is kept by the lambda, in turn preventing garbage collection of `cache` even after the thread leaves `Memoize()`, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions)

Comment: That is way overkill to memoize a variable by the way, holding an entire dictionary for the one value. A dictionary has at least a `List` and a tree (a heap) inside, plus a ton of helper objects to deal with concurrency.

Comment: @Blindy, I think (or hope) the point is to implement a cache for many values.

Comment: @Blindy There would be many values in this dictionary, not just one

Comment: Not the way you wrote it, you create a new dictionary for every call, and push exactly one value in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is creating a kind of a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528603/c-sharp-closure-clarification), because of which the reference to `Dictionary.GetOrAdd` method, via an inner variable `cache`, is still accessible from outside of the `Memorize` method.

Because of this, while **C#** program scope, where the returned function value for the `Memorize` method is still active, will also prevent a Garbage collector from releasing memory for the `Dictionary`.

More about closures also [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-local-functions-in-c-7/).

Comment: so if i'm understanding correctly, because the reference to the object is being returned (it is part of the Func being returned), it will still exist.

Comment: @FrogBaxter, exactly, that's the case.