# What happens if I call a event handler declared inside a function that is not being executed?

Tags: c#, .net

Something like this:

```
    void SomeFunc()
    {
        int InsideVar = 1;
        EventHandler handler = (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show(InsideVar.ToString()); };
        SomeEvent += handler;
    }
```

And then SomeEvent is invoked after SomeFunc is executed. I actually tested it and it worked but cannot understed why. I thought InsideVar would be on the stack and would stop existing after the function is executed. I was expecting an exception. Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, this question will tell you all you need to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net

Answer (score 4):

You've just discovered [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).