# Will the condition on a LINQ Where-statement re-evaluate during the loop?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, refactoring

I have this `foreach`-loop:

```
foreach (var classId in m_ClassMappings[taAddressDefinition.Key])
{
    if(!m_TAAddressDefinitions.ContainsKey(classId))
    {
        m_TAAddressDefinitions.Add(classId, taAddressDefinition.Value);
    }
}
```

`m_TAAddressDefinitions` is an `IDictionary` where classId is used as the unique Key value.
Resharper suggests to change the `if`-statement into into a LINQ filter like this:

```
foreach (var classId in m_ClassMappings[taAddressDefinition.Key].Where(
    classId => !m_TAAddressDefinitions.ContainsKey(classId)))
{
    m_TAAddressDefinitions.Add(classId, taAddressDefinition.Value);
}
```

I am conserned if this might not work as expected, since the content of the `m_TAAddressDefinitions` collection is changing inside the loop, which causes the source of the LINQ filter-condition (`classId => !m_TAAddressDefinitions.ContainsKey(classId)`) to change on the way.

Will this fail if two `classId` with same value is added inside the loop, or will the LINQ condition be recalculated when values are added to the collection? My original if-statement was intended to not cause exception if the key already exist.

Comment: Sometimes, briefer code does not make for more readable code.  The Resharper version is exactly the same as your old version, but as you're finding out, it's harder for you to understand.  I'd recommend in that case to skip that refactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the fact that the `IEnumerable` returned by `Where` in the refactored version will lazily produce values as it is iterated over achieves what you want. The suggestion that includes the `ToList` call is **not** what you want in this case since that would materialize the `IEnumerable` as a collection and you would be vulnerable to there being duplicate `classIds` in the `m_ClassMappings` collection.

The thing to remember is that the predicate in the `Where` call, namely `classId => !m_TAAddressDefinitions.ContainsKey(classId)` will be evaluated for each item as it is produced as a result of iterating over the `IEnumerable`. So in the version suggested by Resharper, if there were duplicate values in the `m_ClassMappings` the first one encountered would be added to the `m_TAAddressDefinitions` but when the next duplicate is reached the `Where` predicate will return false because the value has been previously added to the Dictionary.

Comment: Great answer. This made me understand why it works. No matter, I will still use my original version, and not the LINQ - not because I don't trust it to work, but it is clearer what it does.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested change does not alter the logic. The lambda expression `classId => !m_TAAddressDefinitions.ContainsKey(classId)` will be compiled into a anonymous class where your dictionary is passed in. Since this is a reference and not a copy of it changes to the dictionary will be reflected in the evaluation.

This concept is known as *closure*. See this answer from Jon Skeet for more in depth information: [What are 'closures' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net/428624#428624). And his post [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) is a very code read.

Comment: But I would think the lambda is only called once (even if it's a dynamic reference) because the Where statement is just used to filter a collection, and return a result, which is used as collection on which the for loop is executed.

Comment: No, since LINQ queries use [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/22/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: OK. After reading the [answer by Steve Rowbotham](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765209/will-the-condition-on-a-linq-where-statement-re-evaluete-during-the-loop/7766070#7766070), I understand that your answer is also correct, so I give you +1.

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying `m_ClassMappings` but `m_TAAddressDefinitions`, so the `CollectionModifiedException` will not be raised.

Better rewrite it to

```
m_ClassMappings[taAddressDefinition.Key]
  .Where(classId => !m_TAAddressDefinitions.ContainsKey(classId)))  
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(
    classId => m_TAAddressDefinitions.Add(classId, taAddressDefinition.Value));
```

Comment: I'm not conserned about modified exception on `m_ClassMappings`, but a "key already exists" exception when adding to `m_TAAddressDefinitions` if a classId already have been added previously in the same loop. I have very little experience with LINQ. Is filtered once, and in my case doing a loop on the result, or is the filter re-executed in each loop iteration?

Comment: In LINQ the lamdba inside `Where` (and any method) is evaluated for each loop - so after calling `ToList` you will have list of keys not in the dictionary. You're solution is correct.

Comment: But the list will not be re-populated once inside the loop, so if there are multiple equal classId's within `m_ClassMappings[taAddressDefinition.Key]`, the call to Add will raise exception the second time because none of the classId's were in `m_TAAddressDefinitions` to begin with, but during the loop, the condition change.

Comment: Materializing the `IEnumerable` with `ToList` isn't what you want. See my answer.