# Do delegates create thread safety issues with local variables?

Tags: c#, delegates, scope, local-variables

I am initializing a mutable class instance as a local variable with new keyword. Then I pass this object as a parameteter to a delegate. Is this variable's lifetime extended by the delegate?  Do other threads use this variable or create their own instances? I may be asking the obvious but I want to be sure.

```
public void DoSometing(Action<Foo> action)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    action.Invoke(foo);
}
```

Comment: technically, `Action<Foo>` is not a lambda expression but a delegate.

Comment: You are right. I mixed up the terms here. It cannot even create a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you pass local variables that "escape" the method one way or another, you *do* extend its lifetime.  In C# you will never operate upon a variable that contains a reference to a non-existant object -- the concept makes no sense in a managed environment.

So yes, `foo` will continue to live on, and you will need to be concerned with thread-safety in exactly the same way as if you simply called another ordinary method.  In this scenario, lambdas do not change the complexion of the problem.

However, sometimes this can be more subtle, especially if you *return* a lambda -- one which [closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net) over local variables.  In such a scenario, all the variables you reference from within the lambda live on in the same way as `foo`.

Comment: Ok that's right but each lambda expression will use a new Foo instance right?

Comment: In your example, the *caller* will provide *either* a lambda or a method reference.  In either scenario, each time `DoSomething` is invoked,  a new instance of `foo` will be passed to `action`.  To be precise there is actually no lambda in `DoSomething` at all, merely an instance (`action`) of the *delegate* `Action<Foo>`.