# Inner methods variable scope

Tags: c#, .net

Will the variable uiContext go out scope after the event handler return? What does the compiler do behind the scene to make this code work.

```
private void findButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        string pictures =
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(pictures);
        FileInfo[] allFiles =
            folder.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        FileInfo largest =
            allFiles.OrderByDescending(f => f.Length).FirstOrDefault();

        uiContext.Post(unusedArg =>
        {
            outputTextBox.Text = string.Format("Largest file ({0}MB) is {1}",
                largest.Length / (1024 * 1024), largest.FullName);
        },
        null);
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you know about garbage collection?

Comment: Object is garbage collected when no code parts are referencing it. This means that `uiContext` will be garbage collected when both, thread and method will exit. To be more exact it will become ready for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET uses closures in order to prevent Garbage Collector from deleting the `uiContext` while it is still required by inner methods, actions etc. (here `Task.Factory.StartNew`).

See:

- [What are 'closures' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)
- [What are closures?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/17/53028.aspx)
- [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx)

More over, the `SynchronizationContext` is a class and you don't know if new instance is createad when you use `Current` property or it returns you the existing one. Thus you could be not the only one who have a reference to that instance.