# Save method calls with parameters in list and execute them

Tags: c#, list, reflection, methods

I am pretty new to c# and only scratching the surface. Since my skills are rather limited, I've just reached the limit of what I can do. I would like to populate a list with methods to call (including parameters) and call these methods each second or over any other period of time.

How should I start? I heard about delegates, but I am not sure if they are what I need or if they are suitable for my purposes anyway.

Sorry if this is common-sense.

Comment: Since you've said you're pretty inexperienced, it may be worth re-thinking your approach to whatever problem it is. Can you provide some more context please? Storing a list of methods to call may be unnecessary depending on what they do and under what circumstances they are to be called.

Comment: Especially if you want to store them with their arguments. Why not store the results of those methods in the list?

Comment: There is no limit to what you can do

Comment: A "list of methods to call" sounds like what we call "a program" :)
I wonder what kind of list you mean, and why you think you need to do this...

Comment: Is it one function you wish to call each second, or does the function change each second. How do you know what is the sequence of functions? Should it loop. For executing methods at certain times, you should look in to the `Timer` class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As DeeMac has already said, this doesn't seem like a thing a beginner or C# would likely need and you are best off explaining why you think you need to do this. However, to do what you were saying you could do something like this:

```
    // Here we have the list of actions (things to be done later)
    List<Action> ActionsToPerform;

    // And this will store how far we are through the list
    List<Action>.Enumerator ActionEnumerator;

    // This will allow us to execute a new action after a certain period of time
    Timer ActionTimer;

    public ActionsManager()
    {
        ActionsToPerform = new List<Action>();

        // We can describe actions in this lambda format, 
        // () means the action has no parameters of its own
        // then we put => { //some standard c# code goes here }
        // to describe the action

        // CAUTION: See below

        ActionsToPerform.Add(() => { Function1("Some string"); });
        ActionsToPerform.Add(() => { Function2(3); });

        // Here we create a timer so that every thousand miliseconds we trigger the
        // Elapsed event
        ActionTimer = new Timer(1000.0f);
        ActionTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ActionTimer_Elapsed);

        // An enumerator starts at the begining of the list and we can work through
        // the list sequentially
        ActionEnumerator = ActionsToPerform.GetEnumerator();

        // Move to the start of the list
        ActionEnumerator.MoveNext();

    }

    // This will be triggered when the elpased event happens in out timer
    void ActionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // First we execute the current action by calling it just like a function
        ActionEnumerator.Current();

        // Then we move the enumerator on to the next list
        bool result = ActionEnumerator.MoveNext();

        // if we got false moving to the next, 
        // we have completed all the actions in the list
        if (!result)
        {
            ActionTimer.Stop();
        }
    }

    // Some dummy functions...
    public void Function1(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public void Function2(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing hello {0} times", x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }
```

**Caution**:
Here this works as expected as we just pass in some constant values. However, things get tricky if you are not doing something so trivial. For example consider this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    ActionsToPerform.Add(() => { Function2(i); });
}
```

This won't print out what you expect at all, it is something to do with [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net) which is a very much **not** a beginner topic.

This is in fact the number one reason why you should seriously consider why you need to do this. As you can see, there are some sophisticated concepts here that aren't normally beginner C#...

Comment: Let my try to clarify then. Here is the basic setup: I've got a file, which specifies tasks for users to complete. For each task the author of the file may include as many conditions as he wants for it to complete. Then the file is read by the program and tasks are started under certain circumstances. On the programming side, each and every condition is implemented and should be called repeatedly to check whether all condition methods return true at the same time.

for this to work I think I want to register all condition calls in a list and then iterate over them witch each time step.

Comment: So in the file you have a list of tests and this corresponds to your sequence of actions? Would my above solution be suitable the? As you read the file and map them to the relevant test functions, you add them to the action list?

Comment: Yes to your questions. I am already testing your solution with some variations in the code base. For the most parts it performs just fine, however I am having some issues with Action as it returns no value. For the time being I am using some kind of hack to get bools back for each action, cache them in a list and exit if one value is false. I am also reading into Func, but can't get my head around them yet. Should I expect major performance implications with this ping-pong process or use Func?

Comment: For returns you should be able to do an almost straight swap with `Action` to `Func<bool>` When you call the current Func, you can just check the return as you would normally and stop the timer if it has failed. 
As for performance implications, the standard SO answer is profile it :P There obviously is an overhead as it is one extra layer of indirection, but it won't be noticeable for most cases

Comment: Thank you. This should get me up to speed, although I feel the need to look into Func a little.