# C# process.start arguments from database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, oop, sql-server-ce

```
private void checkDesktopItems()
    {
        SqlCeConnection sqlCnn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\mainDB.sdf");
        SqlCeCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM desktopItems", sqlCnn);
        sqlCnn.Open();
        SqlCeDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (top + 52 < DesktopBounds.Size.Height)
            {
                PictureBox Shapes = new PictureBox();
                Shapes = new PictureBox();
                Shapes.Size = new Size(32, 32);
                Shapes.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                Shapes.Location = new Point(left, top);
                Shapes.Image = ReturnIcon(reader[1].ToString()).ToBitmap();
                Shapes.Visible = true;
                this.Controls.Add(Shapes);
                Shapes.DoubleClick += new EventHandler((o, a) => Process.Start(reader[1].ToString()));
                Shapes.DoubleClick += new EventHandler((o, a) => this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized);

                top += 52;
                y++;
            }
            else
            {
                x++;
                top = 13;
                left += 52;
            }
        }
        sqlCnn.Close();
    }
```

I have this code, anything is working ... except this line `Shapes.DoubleClick += new EventHandler((o, a) => Process.Start(reader[1].ToString()));`

The error says

> No data exists for the row/column.

I want a fix so that every created picturebox to have it`s own eventhandler to start a process.

Comment: reader[1] is not a image ... is a path to an executable

Comment: then you are assigning here as an icon ReturnIcon(reader[1].ToString()).ToBitmap(); so are you sure it's not an image?

Comment: That happens because of closure feature. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net

Comment: @Sudhakar - Yes, I extract the icon from a exe and assign it to a picturebox ... and the same path is used for process.start event :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create local variable, try this:

```
var file = reader[1].ToString();

Shapes.DoubleClick += new EventHandler((o, a) => Process.Start(file));
```

otherwise `reader[1].ToString()` will be evaluated when you `DoubelClick`, which is already too late.

Comment: It works :D. Thank you ... I need to wait 3 more minutes to accept your answer.