# The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is probably really basic in C#, but I looked around a lot to find a solution.

In my MVC controller's action method, I have an incoming routeid (`programid`) that I need to use to create another string variable (`accounttype`). I have an if/else to evaluate the value of `accounttype`. Later in the same action method's code, I have nother if/else that takes the variable `accounttype` and creates a JSON string to pass to a payment gateway. But I get an error `"The name 'accounttype' does not exist in current context.'` Do I need to declare it as public or something?

Here are the two if/else statements:

```
if (programid == 0)
{
    string accounttype = "Membership";
}
else
{
    string accounttype = "Program";
}
```

Later on in same controller action, I need to use the `accounttype` variable to calculate another string variable (URL)

```
if (results.Count() > 0)
{
    string URL = accounttype + "some text"
}
else
{
    string URL = accounttype + "some other text"
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Read about the [*scope*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining your `accounttype` variable within the scope of your `if` and `else` block, so it's not defined outside of those blocks.

Try declaring your variables outside the `if`/`else` blocks:

```
string accounttype;
string URL;
if (programid == 0)
{
    accounttype = "Membership";
}
else
{
    accounttype = "Program";
}

if (results.Count() > 0)
{
    URL = accounttype + "some text"
}
else
{
    URL = accounttype + "some other text"
}
```

Or if your code is really this simple, just use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
string accounttype = programid == 0 ? "Membership" : "Program";
string URL = accounttype + (results.Any() ? "some text" : "some other text");
```

Answer (score 2):

[Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) is your problem :)

Since I guess you are new, I'll try to define it in simple words: the scope of a variable is the place where a variable lives. Not all the variables can be called everywhere in your program, and we call those who can, *global*.

In your case, you are declaring those variables inside an `if .. else` statement, and, because of C# rules, they die as soon as the if block ends. This is what the compiler is telling you: you can't call something that doesn't exist.

To solve your problem, you just have to declare

```
string accounttype;
```

before the `if.. else` and you will be fine.

If you want to read more about scopes, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a good place to start!

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the accounttype is limited to the if statement. Do

```
string accounttype;

if (programid == 0)
{
 accounttype = "Membership";
}
else
{
 accounttype = "Program";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping problem.  Anything inside of braces {} is defined as a block.  Any variables defined in a block are only available within that block and are garbage collected when you exit the block.

Don't define accountType inside the blocks in your if statement:

```
string accounttype;

if (programid == 0)
{
    accounttype = "Membership";
}
else
{
    accounttype = "Program";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scoping is incorrect, try this:

```
string accounttype;
if (programid == 0)
{
    accounttype = "Membership";
}
else
{
    accounttype = "Program";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the scope of the account type variable is in the `{` `}` of the if. you need to declare the variable outside the if to be able to use it after, or even better:

```
string accounttype = programid == 0 ? "Membership" : "Program";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you define the variables within closures, they fall out of scope as soon as you exit those closures.
You need:

```
string URL;
if(test)
{
    URL = "1";
} else {
    URL = "2";
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net). Those are blocks.