# List out of the range

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am building SJF algorithm. I have a dictionary that  I divided it for 2 lists.  one list for the Name and another list for the values. Surely, the dictionary divided after I have sorted it. Also I have a timer.

When, I run the code it crashed in the List and it says to me that

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I do not know how that come, because my loop is exactly the size of the dictionary and to the size of the lists.

Can you please advise my  how can I fix this problem?

```
   //Initializing the Dictionary  and the lists. 
    Dictionary<int, int> waytosave = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    List<int> saveName = new List<int>();
    List<int> saveValue = new List<int>();



   //Botton to run the algorithm 

        private void btnSFJ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //the values inside the dictionary 
        waytosave.Add(0,100);
        waytosave.Add(1,10);
        waytosave.Add(2,30);
        waytosave.Add(3,500);
        waytosave.Add(4,5);
        waytosave.Add(5,13);
        waytosave.Add(6,200);
        waytosave.Add(7,89);
        waytosave.Add(8,248);
        waytosave.Add(9,136);
        waytosave.Add(10,458);
        waytosave.Add(11,743);
```

dividing it to lists seemed the best way for me to get the value and the name at the same time.

```
        //Sort the dictionary by Value
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Int32> saveSFJ in waytosave.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
        {
            saveName.Add(saveSFJ.Key);
            saveValue.Add(saveSFJ.Value);
            txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + "The name is:  " + saveSFJ.Key + "  the value is:  "+ saveSFJ.Value;

        }
        int numsaving = 12;
        int timesaving=0;


        for (int x = 0; x < numsaving; x++)
        {
            var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            int track = 1;
            timer.Tick += (timerObject, timerArgs) =>
            {
                timer.Interval = track * saveValue[x]*1000; //I am getting crashed at this point When ever my loop finished. 
                this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + " the value is:   "
                                                + saveValue[x]
                                                + "The name is:     "
                                                + saveName[x];

                timesaving = timesaving + saveValue[x];
                ++track;
                if (track > numsaving)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    timer.Dispose();

                }
            };
            timer.Start();

        }
        this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + "  Ends x " + timesaving.ToString();

    }
}
```

I am crashing when the loop finish the running and it just runs once

Comment: why not use for `(int x = 0; x < waytosave.Count - 1; x++)` instead of hard coded counter?

Comment: Let me check it. because i try it and just print one value only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop variable `x` gets [captured in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net).

When the delegate behind `timer.Tick` runs, `x` will not be the value it was at the time you created the function, but the *current* value of `x` (since it got captured). At this time, `x` will be equal to `numsaving` (due to the `x++` in the `for` loop).

To solve this, you could copy the value of `x` into another local variable, like:

```
int y = x;
timer.Tick += (timerObject, timerArgs) =>
{
    timer.Interval = track * saveValue[y]*1000; //I am getting crashed at this point When ever my loop finished. 
    this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + " the value is:   "
                                    + saveValue[y]
                                    + "The name is:     "
                                    + saveName[y];

    timesaving = timesaving + saveValue[y];
    ++track;
    if (track > numsaving)
    {
            ...
```

---

You could also use a simple `foreach` loop; and if you're using Visual Studio 2012, you don't have to create a local copy of the iteration variable:

```
foreach(var kvp in waytosave.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
{
    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    int track = 1;
    timer.Tick += (timerObject, timerArgs) =>
    {
        timer.Interval = track * kvp.Value *1000;
        ...
```

Comment: Also see Eric Lippert's post about closures:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Thanks it just work fine. I appreciate your time and your offer. this solves my  problem. thank you  too much

Comment: Yes I am using Visual Studio 2012