# Simplified C-macro-like function calls in C#

Tags: c#, macros

I'm writing a wrapper for a C dll. Various C functions are wrapped for C# applicatons. Now consider some simplified part of the wrapper below.

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
    OK = 0,
    ...
    ...
}

public class AppException: ApplicationException
{
    public AppException(ErrorCode errorCode) : base()
    {
        error = errorCode;
    }

    public ErrorCode error { get; private set; }
}

public class A
{
    public ErrorCode last_ret;
    private IntPtr datap;

    public A(string filename)
    {
        last_ret = (ErrorCode)ClibDllFunc1(filename, out datap);
        if (last_ret != ErrorCode.OK)
            throw new AppException(last_ret);

        // go on processing

        last_ret = (ErrorCode)ClibDllFunc2(datap);
        if (last_ret != ErrorCode.OK)
            throw new AppException(last_ret);
    }

    public void getSize(out int sz)
    {
        last_ret = (ErrorCode)ClibDllFunc3(datap, out sz);
        if (last_ret != ErrorCode.OK)
            throw new AppException(last_ret);
    }

    // ...
    // many functions like these, all working by calling c/c++ dll functions
    // with different number and types of parameters
}

[DllImport("clibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern internal int ClibDllFunc1(string filename, out IntPtr data);

// ... other C function declarations follow similarly
```

As you can see, the wrapper calls various C functions. All C functions return integer as the status code (an ErrorCode), and the wrapper has to check this return code and throw an application defined exception if the C function fails. This has to be done exactly the same way for all C function calls. Only the function name and parameters change but the 3 line calling-block is the same. It looks really cheap in this form as copy/pasted 3-line blocks of function calls.

In C#, is there a way to simplify and encapsulate the "call, check return code, throw exception" cycle in a simpler and more compact way?

For reference (actually this is what I'd like to do to simplify the calls); in C/C++ we can define a macro like this one:

```
#define SAFE_CALL(call) do{ if((last_ret = (ErrorCode)call) != OK) throw AppException(last_ret); }while(0)
```

and call like this:

```
SAFE_CALL(ClibDllFunc1(filename, &datap));
SAFE_CALL(ClibDllFunc2(datap));
SAFE_CALL(ClibDllFunc3(datap, &sz));
```

Comment: Should be able to make a function SAFE_CALL which takes a ClibDllFunc as an arg (returning an int or error code) right?

Comment: @NWard I did exactly the same based on the accepted answer below. It works like a magic. It does the job but I don't understand how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Rereading your problem, I answered the wrong question.  What you really want is a function CheckErrorCode that takes an int, and then simply pass the result of the native call.

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes the result code from invoking a native function.  If the result is
/// not ErrorCode.OK, throws an AppException with that error code.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="returnCodeInt">
/// The return code of a native method call, as an integer. 
/// Will be cast to ErrorCode.
/// </param>
private static void CheckErrorCode(int returnCodeInt)
{
    ErrorCode returnCode = (ErrorCode)returnCodeInt;
    if(returnCode != ErrorCode.OK)
    {
        throw new AppException(returnCode);
    }
}

public void getSize(out int sz)
{
    CheckErrorCode(ClibDllFunc3(datap, out sz));
}
```

## Original text (how to simulate macros with lambdas)

The fact that lambda syntax in C# is so terse means you can use a `Func<T>` in a similar way to macros.  Try something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calls a function's native implementation, then checks if the error code 
/// is not ErrorCode.Ok.  If it is, throws an AppException.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nativeCall">
/// A function that returns the status code as an int.
/// </param>
private static void CheckErrorCode(Func<int> nativeCall)
{
    var returnCode = (ErrorCode)nativeCall();
    if(returnCode != ErrorCode.OK)
    {
        throw new AppException(returnCode);
    }
}
```

You can then call it with:

```
public void getSize(out int sz)
{
    // drawback: compiler can't check that sz is always written.
    sz = 0;
    CheckErrorCode(() => ClibDllFunc3(datap, out sz));
}
```

The lambda creates what's known as a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net).  This is a way to pull the logic of *calling* ClibDllFunc3 (specific to this function) away from the logic of *handling its results* (which is standard across all your DLL functions).  Unlike many closures, this one is called immediately.

Comment: Well, this was simpler than I thought. And it's a surprise to me that it works with "out" parameters as well. Still I don't fully understand how it works. Can you briefly explain what happens right at the lambda expression line? I would read it like "no parameter 'goes to' ClibDllFunc3(datap, out sz)". I didn't think of this because I thought "datap" and "out sz" should be 'going to' ClibDllFunc3 or something.

Comment: While answering these questions, I decided to edit my answer.  While editing my answer, I realized I answered the wrong question.  You don't need lambdas or macros, just a simple method to check the results and throw an exception.