# Android Xamarin programmatically generated Button Click

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating buttons programmatically in Android Xamarin (C#) like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ...
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.Click += delegate {
        processClick(i);
    };
    ...
}
```

the processClick method looks like this:

```
public void processClick(int i) {
    ... Log("i: " + i);
}
```

It successfully creates 3 buttons, but if I press any of them, the console log's number 3. The question is, how handle clicked events of programmatically created buttons?

Comment: Classical closures. Use `var j= i;` inside for-loop and use `processClick(j);`

Comment: You mean: 
b.Click += delegate { int j = i; processClick(j); }; ? I've tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). Rewrite your for loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ...
    Button b = new Button(this);
    var j= i;
    b.Click += delegate {
        processClick(j);
    };
    ...
}
```

Also there is a good [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net) on SO related to this topic.

Comment: I did and it still doesn't work. It still logs number 3;

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I put the var j = i; in the delegate. Solved. Thanks.

Comment: That's my plan, but I can do that in 8 minutes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know about the limit :) Good luck!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue (e.g. 'closure') or at least provide references to good reading material?