# Jagged array of tasks - Concurrency Issues

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I am defining a jagged array of threads (such that each thread can operate on the directory tree of its own) in this manner

```
Task[][] threads = new Task[InstancesDir.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < InstancesDir.Length; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Task[InstancesDir[i].Length];
}
for (int i = 0; i < FilesDir.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < FilesDir[i].Length; j++)
    {
        threads[i][j] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Calculate(i, j, InstancesDir, FilesDir, PointSum);
        });
    }
    Task.WaitAll(threads[i]);
}
```

But in calculate i always get value of j >= FilesDir[i].Length . I have also checked that objects are passed by value except arrays. What could be a workaround for this and what could be the reason for this behavior?

PS. Introducing a shared lock might help in mitigation the concurrency issue but i want to know about the reason for such behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in calculate i always get value of j >= FilesDir[i].Length

This isn't a concurrency issue, as your `for` loop is executing on a single thread. This happens because the lambda expression is closing over your `i` and `j` variables. This effect is called [*Closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net).

In order to avoid it, create a temp copy before passing both variables to `Task.Run`:

```
var tempJ = j;
var tempI = i;

threads[tempI][tempJ] = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Calculate(tempI, tempJ, InstancesDir, FilesDir, PointSum);
});
```

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, this is due to the fact that there is a peculiar "bug" in C# with regards to closures and loop variables (which incidentally is worked around using variables declared inside the loop, such as you do with your temp variables).

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bug. This is by design. See [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Comment: I actually expect this to be by accident, since any other variable (as far as I know), except loop variables, behave differently (and get's properly closed over if you use them in the closure), but I might be wrong, and it might be a weird perf thing. I just find it weird that first of all the behave differently, and second of all they by choice wandered into the pitfall of loops and closures you have in javascript.