# Passing string parameter to method in multi-threaded C# application

Tags: c#, string, multithreading

I have some application that passes a string parameter to a method that is invoked using a thread inside a loop like this, this thread is create 50 times

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    StartExtraction( savedFileName);
}));
t.Name = "do";
t.Start();
```

in the ***StartExtraction*** method I noticed that the parameters are overwritten , I mean if the first invocation was with savedFileName="abc" and the second was with savedFilename="xyz" ,the method always processes "xyz", I mean  StartExtraction when debugged, the parameter is overwritten, , why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why?

Because that is how [*closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net) works. It closes over the variable, not the value. If you change the value of `savedFileName`, that is what you'll see inside the captured delegate.

In order for this to set the expected value, you'll need to store it inside a local variable inside your captured lambda:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    var temp = savedFileName;
    StartExtraction(temp);
}));
t.Name = "do";
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what has already been answered, you would need to store the value of `savedFileName` into a temporary variable within your loop and use that instead of `savedFileName` in order to avoid the closure.

As an example see the answer already provided here:

[Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)