# What is the purpose of "() =>" in lambda c#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have been trying to figure this out and it's really bugging me. I have some code that looks like this

```
static T MyFunction<T>(Func<T> action, int i, int i2)
{
    ...some code here
}
```

When I need to call this code I tried this

```
var result = MyFunction<List<string>>(MethodThatReturnsListofString(int number), 1,2)
```

It fails stating that the best overload has invalid arguments
But when I tried the following

```
var result = MyFunction<List<string>>(() => MethodThatReturnsListofString(int number), 1,2)
```

It works fine. What is the function of "() =>" in this case. I thought() could not be used with methods required more than 0 args.

Comment: `MethodThatReturnsListofString(int number)` makes no sense; you're passing a parameter, not declaring a function.  Please show actual code.

Comment: `Func<T> action` ...

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to make my question clearer and may have obscured the issue in trying to do so. MethodTheReturnsListOfString takes a single integer argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyFunction<T>` expects as first parameter a method that takes no arguments and returns the type `T`.

**In your first attempt,** you call `MethodThatReturnsListofString(number)` and try to provide the result (a `List<T>`) as parameter instead of a method.

**In your second try,** you create a method with the required signature by typing `() => MethodThatReturnsListofString(number)` and provide this as parameter.

---

To make it more clear, you could have created a method like

```
static List<T> MyAnonymousMethod()
{
    return MethodThatReturnsListofString(number);
}
```

and then called

```
MyFunction<List<string>>(MyAnonymousMethod, 1, 2);
```

With `() => MethodThatReturnsListofString` you declare an **anonymous method inline** and so you don't need to create `MyAnonymousMethod` first. This part of your code is what is called a **lambda expression**.

---

**Note** that by declaring this lambda, `MethodThatReturnsListofString` is not executed immediatly! It will be executed only when `MyFunction` really calls this action parameter like

```
static T MyFunction<T>(Func<T> action, int i, int i2)
{
    // ... some code
    var result = action();
    // ... more code
}
```

Comment: So I'm creating an anonymous method that takes no arguments, to hold the result of a method that takes a number?

Comment: @Rocky Indeed. Note that when `MyFunction` actually calls this `action`, the then current value of `number` will be used. This may already differ from the value it had when calling `MyFunction`

Comment: Ah. I can probably account for that by being careful how I manipulated the value of number while it is being called.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing a lambda that takes no arguments.
That is the correct syntax to write such a lambda.

The fact that your lambda happens to call a function that takes arguments is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Perhaps my fundamental understanding of Lambda is incorrect. What part of the call I am making is considered the lambda? To attempt to make my question more clear, you say I am passing a lambda that takes no arguments. what part of my "correct" call is that lambda?

Comment: Yes; you are misunderstanding things.  The lambda consists of the parameters prefix (`() =>`) and the body that specifies the return value (in your case, a function call).

Comment: So `() =>` is just a placeholder for a method that doesn't really exist, that takes no arguments, and returns, in my case, the result of the method call to `MethodThatReturnsListOfString(int)`??

Comment: @Rocky: It isn't a placeholder; it's the syntax to declare a nested method.  Read the documentation.

Comment: I actually have read the docs, I just found them a bit confusing. Thank you for helping me to understand a bit better though. So the `() => ` doesn't "hold" and place, it instead declares an anonymous method on the fly that will contain and return the result of the method called on the right side of the lambda expression, regardless of the number of arguments that second method happens to call. This works because the lambda takes no actual arguments, thus fulfilling the requirement of `Func<T> action`. correct?

Answer (score 3):

This simply means that you are invoking an anonymous method which accepts 0 arguments. 
If its () => a+b

it returns the addition

else if you provide it a body

like ()=> { } its upto you to return or not

also if you provide the delegate which needs it to return then you have to return. for eg Action doesnt require but Func do require

Answer (score 1):

```
MethodThatReturnsListofString(number)
```

is not a `Func<T>`. It is a `Func<T, U>`, where `List<string>` is one type argument and `int` is the other. Moreover, you are providing the *result* of this method — not the method itself — as the argument to your function.

On the other hand, this expression is a `Func<T>`:

```
() => MethodThatReturnsListofString(number)
```

This is a lambda expression that creates a **delegate** with no input parameters and one output parameter (the `List<string>`). The `number` variable passed to `MethodThatReturnsListofString()` is **not** part of the function definition. The code works because the `number` variable is instead a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net). The variable is captured by the compiler and used by the method, but it's not part of the method signature.

> I thought `()` could not be used with methods required more than 0 args.

That is correct. But remember that the `Func<T>` type used for your `action` argument here defines a function that accepts 0 arguments and returns one value. So what you are doing is matching your expression to the `Func<T>` type of `MyFunction`'s `action` parameter. Just because you then call a method that requires an argument within your new `Func<T>` delegate doesn't mean the delegate itself requires an argument.