# delegate and lambda expression task

Tags: c#, .net

could you explain me one example with delegate and lambda expression

```
List<Func<int>> list = new List<Func<int>>(); 
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     list.Add(() => i);
 }
 foreach (var func in list)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(func());
 }
```

I understand, that I have List of refers to methods whithout params and  returns Int, but why it returns 10 times  max value from loop? How it works? Thx!

Comment: Because the lambda expression will capture the variable it self, not a copy of its value. After the first loop is done, this variable will have the max value.

Comment: Because when you run your `Func<int>`s the value of `i` is 10.  You need to create a local variable in the `for` loop to capture the value and use that instead of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass variable inside of delegate's method it is its link, and not it's value that is used inside the delegate.

We create list of functions:

```
 List<Func<int>> list = new List<Func<int>>();
```

Here we initialize list with functions and every function should use reference to memory where `i` variable is stored when it's fired :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     list.Add(() => i);
 }
```

Now it is time  to fire each function but at this time `for` loop is already finished executing and `i` variable holds its final value of 10. Remember that delegate can always find parameter because it holds reference to it. It could not be garbage collected :

```
 foreach (var func in list)
 {
      // by the time we do it it has value of 10
      Console.WriteLine(func());
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It is closure when you do:

```
(() => i)
```

The lambda gets the original variable `i`, not a copy, so you get 10 ten times - because on calling delegate the original value of `i` is 10 (after loop)

If you change code and add local temp variable you will get 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     int j = i;
     list.Add(() => j);
 }
```

You can read about closures here:
[Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that the lambda `() => i` *captures* the local variable `i`. This means that `i` will not be evaluated when it is added to the list but when you actually invoke the lambda with `()`.

At the time this happens in your code (`Console.WriteLine(func());`) the value of `i` is already `10` because the `for` loop has finished.

If you want to avoid this behaviour you have to copy the value of `i` into a local variable that will *not change* after the lambda has been created.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     int tmp = i;
     list.Add(() => tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the lambda expression is a delegate, and you calling it after the loop ends and at that time `i` has value **10**, so when the delegates are getting called, they all have `i` value **10** as same copy is used due to closure, you will need to write as @Roma suggested for it to work as you expect it to, otherwise it will,

this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     list.Add(() => i);
 }
```

can be looked as :

```
 int i;
 for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
 {
     list.Add(() => i);
 }
```