# Why is my list (from .Where) updating its elements by itself?

Tags: c#

I'm coding a bot for a game, in which several players have different actions and use them to interact with each other.

One of the actions I'm coding chooses 2 players (A and B), and makes every other player that was targeting A, target B instead, and vice versa.

However, with my code, only players targeting B have their target swapped. If a player is targeting A initially, my code changes it to B and then changes it to A back.

```cs
var target1 = Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == doorman.Choice);
var target2 = Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == doorman.Choice2);

if (target1 != null && target2 != null)
{
    var going1 = Players.Where(x => x.Choice == target1.Id && x.Id != doorman.Id);
    var going2 = Players.Where(x => x.Choice == target2.Id && x.Id != doorman.Id);

    foreach (var visitor in going1)
        visitor.Choice = target2.Id;

    foreach (var visitor in going2)
        visitor.Choice = target1.Id;
}
```

I think the problem is that the list `going2` gets updated even after being declared, and has all the players in `going1` added to it.

This means all players that are targeting `target1` are swapped to `target2` and then back to `target1`.

How can I make my `going1` and `going2` lists not update by themselves after being declared?

Comment: You might want to force the evaluation of your `Where()` calls with a `.ToList()` statement.

Comment: You might want to look up the term "deferred execution" and possibly have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7324033/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47379362/11683.

Comment: lists `going1` and `going2` and the list `Players` are referencing to the same source, so any change in any of these will reflect in all of them (as you did in both foreach loops). you have declared `going1` and `going2` as new lists but they only have references to the source!

Comment: If you do not want original changed, then you need to clone the originals.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `.ToList()` after `Where`

```
var going1 = Players.Where(x => x.Choice == target1.Id && x.Id != doorman.Id).ToList();
var going2 = Players.Where(x => x.Choice == target2.Id && x.Id != doorman.Id).ToList();
```

As Linq `.Where` will return `Enumerable` list it will be evaluated again when you try to access `going1` & `going2` objects inside `foreach`. But if you use `.ToList()` then it will immediately evaluate value and assign it to `going1` & `going2` objects.