# One "simple" problem about building LINQ query drives me crazy

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<char> query = "Not what you might expect";

query = query.Where(c=>c!='a');
query = query.Where(c=>c!='e');
query = query.Where(c=>c!='i');
query = query.Where(c=>c!='o');
query = query.Where(c=>c!='u');

foreach(char c in query) Console.Write(c);
```

Simple LINQ query building. 
My question is, why all this queries execute? Why not only the last one?
How this is compiled, how program knows to return to query initialization?
I hope you understand my question.

I Know this code works and it's intuitive, but what happens behind the scenes?

Comment: You're assigning the result of each filter back to the query variable. Why wouldn't each one execute?

Comment: Consider about it like about a `StringBuilder`, by calling `builder.Append(value).Append(another)` you will collect all data which need to be in the final string and by calling `.ToString()` you actually build a new string.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. The last line does in fact execute.
The "when" the `Where` statements are evaluated will be during GetEnumerator within your ForEach loop.

Comment: query variable executes after foreach... so why program goes on query initialization?

Comment: Are you asking why each `Where` is executed for each iteration of the `foreach`? This would be due to LINQ being lazily evaluated.

Comment: _so why program goes on query initialization_ - what you mean by "query initialization"?

Comment: deferred execution

Comment: [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) returns an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) (basically an enumerator); it does not "execute" anything. The execution is done when you iterate over the results, as you do with the `foreach`. So each call to `.Where` is simply returning a new `IEnumerable` with the added condition.

Comment: You might read this article for more information: [Basic Linq Query Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to write it this way, only the last query would execute:

```
IEnumerable<char> source = "Not what you might expect";

query = source.Where(c=>c!='a');
query = source.Where(c=>c!='e');
query = source.Where(c=>c!='i');
query = source.Where(c=>c!='o');
query = source.Where(c=>c!='u');

foreach(char c in query) Console.Write(c);
```

Only the last query executes because each line *replaces* the queries assigned above it.

Your example, on the other hand, is equivalent to this:

```
IEnumerable<char> source = "Not what you might expect";

query = source.Where(c=>c!='a').Where(c=>c!='e').Where(c=>c!='i').Where(c=>c!='o').Where(c=>c!='u');

foreach(char c in query) Console.Write(c);
```

In this example, each line *appends* to the queries assigned above it. So obviously all of the queries will execute.

Comment: Yes,I figured out something. When function return IEnumerable program does nothing with it. Just remebers somewhere that it is called. Only when foreach starts (asks for enumerator) functions are executed. I'm I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. It's called [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379362/how-does-deferred-linq-query-execution-actually-work). If you want immediate execution, simply call `ToList()`, and LINQ will execute immediately and put everything into a List data structure.

Comment: Yes yes that's right.. defered execution. Now i cleared! Thanks