# Is there a performance penalty when using a Select() inside a lambda Where() clause?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, lambda

Stumbled upon something while trying to evaluate which events I need to create.

I had a code like this:

```
var eventsToBeCreated = 
            requiredEventDates.Where(d => !events.Select(e => e.eventDay).Contains(d));
```

But it made me wonder if this is not such a good idea performance wise, because I believe (I am not sure) the `Select()` gets evaluated individually for every element, so I changed it to:

```
var existingEventDays =
            events.Select(e => e.eventDay);
        
var eventsToBeCreated = 
            requiredEventDates.Where(d => !existingEventDays.Contains(d));
```

But I was not sure about this either. As `existingEventdays` is an `IEnumerable<DateTime>` I guess this would still lead to the enumerable to be resolved multiple times? So I changed it to:

```
var existingEventDays =
            events.Select(e => e.eventDay).ToList();
        
var eventsToBeCreated = 
            requiredEventDates.Where(d => !existingEventDays.Contains(d));
```

..to make sure that the `existingEventDays` get calculated only one time.

Are my assumptions correct or is this not necessary and the first version would offer the same performance as the third?

Comment: Any performance difference is highly likely to depend on the backing data.  Are these operations being performed in-memory against in-memory data?  Are they expression trees being evaluated against a SQL data source?  Something else?  Any way you look at it, profiling and measuring the differences are the only real way to determine what those differences are.

Comment: @David The operations are being performed in-memory only (working with DateTime objects). No SQL DB is involved.

Comment: In your example case I'd use `Except`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you actually consume the whole query created with `Where`, like calling `ToList()`. If you don't consume it, then nothing in the `Where` lambda is executed. You're just creating a bunch of `IEnumerable<T>`s. See [Deferred Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47379362/5133585).

Regarding the second snippet, you extracted the `Select` call to a variable, this indeed causes `events.Select` to only be called once, instead of once for every element in `requiredEventDates`. But again, due to [Deferred Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47379362/5133585), calling `Select` itself is not very expensive. It is the *looping* that `Contains` does that is usually expensive.

Regarding the third snippet, you first made a list out of the dates from the `events`. This loops through the entirety of `events`. And `Contain` loops through the list for each element in `requiredEventDates`, *on top of that*. So you essentially looped through the whole list one more time than necessary.

To avoid all this looping, you can instead put the dates into a `HashSet`:

```
var existingEventDays =
            events.Select(e => e.eventDay).ToHashSet();
        
var eventsToBeCreated = 
            requiredEventDates.Where(d => !existingEventDays.Contains(d));
```

Now you only loop through `events` once, to create the set. And `Contains` looks up `d` in the set, which can be a lot faster than looking things up in a list.