# Does C# foreach create a copy of the element from an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, ref

In what cases foreach uses a ref, and in what cases foreach uses a copy?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class A {
    public int v;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main() {
        var ints = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
        
        var array = ints.Select(i=>new A {v = i}).ToArray();
        foreach(var a in array) {
            a.v = 999;
        }

        var enumerable = ints.Select(i=>new A {v = i});
        foreach(var a in enumerable) {
            a.v = 999;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"array.First = {array.First().v}");
        Console.WriteLine($"enumerable.First = {enumerable.First().v}");
    }
}
```

jdoodle.com/ia/Jce

Output:

```
array.First = 999
enumerable.First = 0
```

Seems that in `foreach(var a in enumerable) {` a is copy not a ref, while in `foreach(var a in array) {` a is a ref.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how reference-types and Linq's lazy-evaluation work - and what `ToArray` actually does... because `foreach` doesn't do what you think it does here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really about `foreach`. It has more to do with how you constructed `array` and `enumerable`. `foreach` does the same thing in both cases (getting the enumerator and calling `MoveNext` and `Current` to iterate through the enumerable). It is the difference between `enumerable` and `array` that causes the difference in output.

`array` is an `A[]`, so if you change the `v`s of its elements, and then get the first of those element, you will obviously see the change. `A` is a reference type, so `a` in the `foreach` is a reference to the element in the array.

`enumerable` however, is something produced by `Select`. Nothing substantial is done if you just call `Select`. It just creates an `IEnumerable<A>`, that **when enumerated over**, creates a bunch of `A` objects. The important point here is that the `Select` lambda is run whenever `enumerable` is being enumerated. If you don't enumerate it, nothing happens. This is called [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379362/how-does-deferred-linq-query-execution-actually-work).

So the second `foreach` enumerates `enumerable`, creating a bunch of `A` objects, and you then change the `v`s of those `A`s. Here is the important difference - the `A` objects don't get stored anywhere, unlike with an array. You "threw" away the `A` object after each iteration.

When you call `enumerable.First()` at the end, you start enumerating `enumerable` again - only once this time because you want only the first element. And what does `enumerable` do? It creates a new `A` object by running the code in `Select`.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Select` uses deferred execution and returns a query that is "executed" while using the `foreach` or `GetEnumerator` method. `.ToArray()` returns an `[]` that contains the objects.

The first for loop iterates over the actual objects and modifies the values of the elements, while the second for loop projects each element of the sequence. Executing `.First()` on `enumerable`, projects the elements again and uses the original `ints` to return the first element from the list

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is an instance of deferred execution vs non-deferred execution.

Take the following example:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    // Note where this gets set in Main!
    static int x = 0;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        var a = arr.Select(f => {
            Console.WriteLine("Evaluated");
            return f + x;
        });

        // This will affect how the above Select evaluates things.
        x = 5;

        foreach (var d in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
    }
}
```

When we do our `foreach`, the code in the `Select` will be run for each item in `a` (i.e., we will enumerate over `a` and run the console writeline and f + x each time we grab an item in `a`).

As soon as we tack on `ToArray()`, the evaluation has to happen immediately, meaning we no longer defer execution.

In your example, since we call `ToArray()` immediately, it means we immediately get a bunch of references to `A` objects.  Additionally, since the evaluation happens on that line, we have a place that we're storing them.

With your `enumerable` variable, the evaluation of `new A()` results in us creating an `A` object each time we iterate in the `foreach`, but the `A` object we just made isn't apart of the original `enumerable` collection, so it's lost.

You'll see things more clearly if you take my example and run it with and without a call to `ToArray()` on the line with `Select()`.