# Why does my viewmodel return only last value while post to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am posting a form from the view to the controller using `Beginform` method, and passing a list of id's through a hidden field.

But it returns only the last value in the list.

`View.cshtml`:

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("makepayment","home",FormMethod.Post))
 {
     if (Model != null) 
     {
         for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
         {
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].cart.vid)
         }
    }
                               
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].payment.cname);
 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].payment.number);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].payment.securitycode);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m[0].payment.expdate);
    <input type="submit" value="pay" />
 }
```

It only returns the last value. The loop isn't working because I used `IEnumerable`, but I don't know how to solve

Comment: Change `[0]` to `[i]`?

Comment: @CodeCaster the problem is with the first block,@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].cart.vid)

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar  sir ,THis is wat i asked

Comment: @Rashid AN sir can u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a closure problem, see [Understanding Closures](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-csharp-features-6-closure)

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    var index = i;
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[index].cart.vid)
}
```

Comment: thank u for your response,But in the controller,i cant put this value in the  db,Actually i don't know well how to do this

Comment: public ActionResult makepayment(List<paymentcart> c)
  my controller and payment cart is my viewmodel,how to add this to database?Am using stored procedure?

Comment: Are you referring to the 'index' variable value? If so, you don't need to add it to your database or your controller, it's just a temporary loop variable. This problem has to do with WHEN Lambda functions (in this case the 'm => Model[i].cart.vid' line of code) are executed as well as the scope in which they were created. Here's another link which explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net