# How can I pass a string and a DataTable to a backgroundworker C# WinForms

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a WinForm that a user can select some options and then click a button. The button reads the users options from the screen and determines which DB connection string to use. I want to pass the connection string and an empty DataTable to a backgroundworker in a different class. The background worker will then connect to the db, retrieve the data and return the datatable to be bound to a datagrid on the main form.

I've got everything working with the exception of being able to pass the DataTable.

So, my question is there a way to pass two different data types to a BGW? Or is it possible to wrap the string and datatable into a single object?

Comment: `Is it possible to wrap the string and DataTable into a single object?` Sure. You know how to create a class, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to wrap the string and datatable into a single object?

If you need to pass two objects as a single object, you make a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) and... wait, we have Tuple. Just create a tuple with two items of the types you need and pass that.

You can use [`System.Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=netframework-4.8), more precisely `System.Tuple<T1, T2>`, which is a [**class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) with two [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) `Item1` and `Item2`.

`Tuple`:

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(connectionString, dataTable);
```

Using [`System.ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8), or more precisely `System.ValueTuple<T1, T2>` which is a [**struct**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs) with two [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) `Item1` and `Item2`, will also work (although it would be [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)).

`ValueTuple`:

```
var tuple = (connectionString, dataTable);
```

See also [Named and unnamed tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples).

---

> is there a way to pass two different data types to a BGW

The event handler to [`DoWork`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork?view=netframework-4.8) is not limited to the object you pass in [`RunWorkerAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerAsync_System_Object_). It could read [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) of the type where it is declared. Or, if it is a lambda expression, it can also use local variables from the context (see [What are 'closures' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)).