# Do values of array i check against in expression are stored in Expression<Func<T,bool>>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, where-clause

So i have a one class to deal with strings, splitting them and setting the whole expression (There is more than just contriesNames, but iam not introducing it here to make it simpler):

```
public class DealWithExpression
{
     public void DealWithExpression(Params params)
     {
        string[] countriesNames = {};
        if(params.Countries != null)
           countriesNames = params.Countries.Split(','); // params got Countries string prop.

        HandleQuery(someQuery, x => countriesNames.Contains(db.table.Name))
     }
}
```

And i have another class that gets the query from database and is supposed to filter with expected `Filter` expressions:

```
public class DealWithQuery()
{
     HandleQuery(IQueryable<TEntity> inputQuery, Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter)
     {
          var query = inputQuery;

           if(Filter != null)
           {
               query.Where(Filter);
           }
     }
}
```

I think the expression i store in `Filter` object doesn't store the `string[] countriesNames` and it doesn't know what to compare against, but iam not sure. I dont want to store additional string arrays in DealWithQuery class, is there a way to do it? To avoid cluttering the classes?

Comment: You can achieve this by declaring a function of a function that takes in a list of strings (your filter). Now you have a function with a list in it that you can call from a LINQ statement. These functions are similar to "higher order functions"
See below for an example:
`Func<List<string>, Func<string, bool>> filter = list => str => list.Contains(str);
var queryParameters = new List<string>() {"Nike", "Sweden", "Large"};
var countries = new List<string>() {"Germany", "Sweden", "Denmark"};
var countryFilter = filter(countries);
var filteredList = queryParameters.Where(countryFilter);`

Comment: Shamless plug: I've written a [VS debugging visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer) that allows you to inspect the structure of an expression tree; point it at `someQuery.Expression` and you'll be able to see the expression used to generate the query, including any closed-over variables. Also, if `countriesNames` is empty, I'm guessing the query won't return any results, because `countriesNames` doesn't contain any of the values; this may or may not be desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will actually store the collection. You can check that as simple as that:

```
var x = new[] {"a","b"};
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr = s => x.Contains(s);
Console.WriteLine(expr.Compile()("a")); // prints "True"
Console.WriteLine(expr.Compile()("a1")); // prints "False"
```

This is called [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net). Closures in C# are achieved using special compiler generated class (and works for anonymous functions and expression trees as well). You can check decompilation [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AMgJYB2AjgNyEnlV1OUCiCADrADOQ2hHpDWRAMzkspAMKkA3oVLq16reoyyMKUgFkcACgCUKzdvUBIAG4BDKKQSkAvKXowA7gG0AuioARA5BADRBwEEAvlI2GACsADwUxGGkwBAQADYAfKQwAs4eQu75CJQK4gAuDgxCJkJmcRQAnCaFgiYhQWbNVqTRAwPauuQGhuaWBNZa9k4u7p4+AcGhEVGxhDZ8gjAiYvQpyanpmTm5+Z3FpKVu5ZU1dRKN/QTxOO3XjwC2/LTZGDmbqhPpSbRDAjRIA) yourself. Or with something similar to your [original code](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=).

Comment: That's weird because it doesn't filter my query at all, i checked with debugger and for sure i got the string[] there from params iam sending, it adds the Expression to my Filter but it doesn't work when iam  adding it in query.Where(filter)

Comment: @PTK check the query which hits the db with the profiler first.