# CheckBoxes coloring by checking (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, checkbox, colors

I have three colored CheckBoxes. Each checkbox should be marked by checking. But when I move the mouse over the checkboxes, all checkboxes are selected in a monotonous color. How should I change the code (see below)? Thanks in advance!

```
private CheckBox[] checkboxes;

private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   checkboxes = new[] {checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3 };

   foreach(var CK in checkboxes)
   {
     CK.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(CK_Paint);
   }
}

private void CK_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   if (checkBox1.Checked)
   {
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 13, 13);
   }
   if (checkBox2.Checked)
   {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, 13, 13);
   }
   if (checkBox3.Checked)
   {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 13, 13);
            
   }

}
```

Comment: Try using a local variable in foreach loop. 

   foreach(var CK in checkboxes)
   {
      CheckBox local=CK;
     local.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(CK_Paint);
   }


 If it solves your problem take a look at this article for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a mouse hover event and set the background color?

Comment: Alternatively, the `sender` argument is the actual checkbox that raised the event so maybe you could just cast sender to a checkbox and do whatever with it

Comment: I do not think you want to use the “CheckBoxes” `Paint` event for this. This event will fire often like when the user simply hovers over a check box. So, the checked state of the check box will obviously NOT change in that situation. Therefore, calling the code is unnecessary. I would think that the combo boxes `CheckedChanged` event would be more appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately the local variable is not working well. Thanks for your advice " Ali Ihsan Elmas"

Comment: Perhaps it might helb, but i want to checking the checkboxes. Thank you for your information "Caius Jard". And please see my comments further below.

Comment: An interesting approach " Caius Jard".  Do you think something like this: foreach(Control c in this.Controls { if(c is CheckBox) { if(((CheckBox)c).Checked == true) // do something}} ??

Comment: I think you are right, "John G". The event will fire often when the user simply hovers the checkboxes. Thank you for pointing that out. If use of following code: private void CheckBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) { if (checkBox1.Checked) { e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red,0,0,13,13);}} This works for me. Actually, my intention was to get a compact representation of the code.