# Add variable property/field name in the contains when creating an expression tree

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Consider expression tree below,

```cs
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "b");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "FirstName");
var abc = new string[] { "a", "b" };
MethodInfo contains = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(nameof(Enumerable.Contains)))
    .Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(property.Type);
var body = Expression.Call(contains, Expression.Constant(abc), property);
```

when we view this code in into debug we see the query generated by the body (variable) is:

```
.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(
    .Constant<System.String[]>(System.String[]),
    $b.FirstName)
```

and when we inspect the where in (`var results = customers.Where(x => abc.Contains(x.FirstName)).ToList();`) we get this:

```
.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(
    .Constant<Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0>(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).abc,
    $x.FirstName)
```

How do you add the **abc** like in the where in the expression tree ?

**Notes** abc is: `var abc = new string[] { "a", "b" }` (see code above)

Comment: Probaly `Expression.MakeMemberAccess` will help, but you did not explain what `abc` is.

Comment: abc is variable array var abc = new string[] { "a", "b" };

Comment: by curiosity how would you add the Expression.MakeMemberAccess in there ?

Comment: I don't know by heart, but a look at the parameters of the `MakeMemberAccess` method should give you clues (of course only if `.abc` was a real member access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Add this:

```cs
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
// Displays as:
// b => value(System.String[]).Contains(b.FirstName)

var compiled = (Func<Customer, bool>)lambda.Compile();
```

You can test it with:

```cs
var cust = customers.Where(compiled).ToList();
// I get the expected result with some test data.
```

Note: the expression above may look awkward, but this is due to the fact that the expression captures the local variable in a compiler generated class named `<>c__DisplayClass0_0`.

See this [answer form user295190](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142956/880990) to the question [What are 'closures' in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428617/880990)

You cannot see this compiler generated code in your expression, because it is probably created when being compiled (call to `Compile()`).